Null exception during user login ASP.NET Core Identity
I am fairly new to ASP.NET Core. I am working on a simple social media web app and decided to add Identity to my existing User. I am having trouble with signing the user in. The problem occurs in both Login and Register methods. In the Register method, the user is actually added to the database.

But when trying to sign in inside the very same method I get the following:

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(string paramName)

System.ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(object argument, string paramName)  
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer, string originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, string propertyKey, string propertyValue)  
System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(string type, string value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>.CreateAsync(TUser user)   
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable<Claim> additionalClaims)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, bool isPersistent, string loginProvider, bool bypassTwoFactor)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager<TUser>.PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)  
ImagiArtInfrastructure.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginViewModel model) in AccountController.cs


My app already had User model class, so I added the missing tables to the database.

My current User model, which inherits from IdentityUser:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ImagiArtInfrastructure;

public partial class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();

    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; } = new List<Like>();
    
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserFollower> UserFollowerFollowers { get; set; } = new List<UserFollower>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserFollower> UserFollowerUsers { get; set; } = new List<UserFollower>();
}

Register and Login methods:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = new User
        {
            Email = model.Email,
            UserName = model.Email
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // cookies
            // This line causes the exception
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string? returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= "/";
    return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This line causes the exception too
        var result =
        await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login credentials");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

Program.cs
using ImagiArtInfrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CloneContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

// Adding Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<int>>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<CloneContext>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Database context:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ImagiArtInfrastructure;

public partial class CloneContext : IdentityDbContext<User, IdentityRole<int>, int>
{
    public CloneContext()
    {
    }

    public CloneContext(DbContextOptions<CloneContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<UserFollower> UserFollowers { get; set; }

    // Warning  CS0114  'CloneContext.Users' hides inherited member 'IdentityUserContext<User, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>>.Users'.
    // if Users is uncommented
    //public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-6SAKF27\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Clone; Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True; ");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.CommentId).HasName("PK__Comments__E7957687FE981422");

            entity.Property(e => e.Caption)
                .HasMaxLength(64)
                .HasColumnName("caption");
            entity.Property(e => e.PostId).HasColumnName("post_id");
            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Post).WithMany(p => p.Comments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("comments_post_id_foreign");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Comments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Comments_AspNetUsers");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Like>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.LikeId).HasName("PK__Likes__992C79308223B6DD");

            entity.Property(e => e.PostId).HasColumnName("post_id");
            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Post).WithMany(p => p.Likes)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PostId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("likes_post_id_foreign");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Likes)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Likes_AspNetUsers");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PostId).HasName("PK__Posts__3ED78766917B0BC9");

            entity.Property(e => e.Caption)
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .HasColumnName("caption");
            entity.Property(e => e.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(64)
                .HasColumnName("description");
            entity.Property(e => e.ImageUrl)
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("image_url");
            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.Posts)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Posts_AspNetUsers");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserFollower>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.UserFollowId).HasName("PK__UserFoll__15A691442B4B1096");

            entity.Property(e => e.FollowerId).HasColumnName("follower_id");
            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnName("user_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Follower).WithMany(p => p.UserFollowerFollowers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FollowerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_UserFollowers_AspNetUsers1");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany(p => p.UserFollowerUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_UserFollowers_AspNetUsers");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

I tried debugging to see what exactly is causing this.
SignInManager class Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity:
/// <summary>
/// Creates a <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for the specified <paramref name="user"/>, as an asynchronous operation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">The user to create a <see cref="ClaimsPrincipal"/> for.</param>
/// <returns>The task object representing the asynchronous operation, containing the ClaimsPrincipal for the specified user.</returns>
public virtual async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user) => await ClaimsFactory.CreateAsync(user); // ClaimsFactory.CreateAsync(user) causes the exception

I noticed that the user parameter is passed correctly everywhere, so no idea what causing this.

Sorry, I didn't want to paste even more walls of text, fixed it.

Is the password value present? Perhaps it didn't bind properly during user post?

Yes, the password is being passed correctly alongside username (which is same as email in my case). CheckPasswordAsync in SignInManager is true as well. Also, I am not sure about the right way (or even whether should I) to provide code that is not directly inside my project, so apologies for that.

Moreover, apparently the user is able to sign in, which is proved by CheckPasswordSignInAsync method returning SignInResult.Success. So I think the problem is with claims not generating properly or not at all? I am confused :(

I agree with dpant's answer, I also know your requirement, I have a similar requirement, and I create the login/register api like this: https://github.com/Jason446620/AspNetCore7/blob/master/AspCore7_Web_Identity/Controllers/UsersController.cs

Thanks for the repo, I had a look at it. So you mean that upon register, even though the user is added to the database, they are lost somewhere because of the primary key?
As of now when the user is added they are assigned ID “0”. But since the Identity’s default ID type is string, there is no auto increment, though I thought server management studio would still take care of that. As a result, I can only register one user for now and try to log them in.

@user729 but you've set it to int instead. Can you please take a look at the database table itself? Also, simplify your code by commenting out all entities related to User and see if you can register a user. That error message shows up when a value is missing when related entities are instantiated and can be a bit misleading.

Yes, the Id type is set to 'int' in my database, it wouldn't let me add users otherwise. My solution was to make the EF create an Identity database itself and just modify it. So I just messed up somewhere, thanks for your time and help though.

@user729 Even though you seem a bit reluctant to follow any advice, here is a final word of help: modifying the Id type manually (in the database) after the DbContext has been defined is known to be problematic. Please, define your model with the desired Id type first and then re-create the database. Also, I cannot stress this enough: you need to special configuration to have it up and running. It works fine by default. Please, remove any redundant Fluent configuration. All your other conclusions (as per your comments) are wrong. Good luck.

Well, thanks for your time and being patient with me. Sadly, I can't upvote anything yet.

My solution was to create a new Identity database and add whatever tables you need for the web app. The problem might have been that I added Identity tables to the database using queries inside SSMS and that screwed something up.
I tried it in a new project. The EF can create the Identity database for you. I added a connection string and create a new class:
public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options)
: base(options)
{
    Database.EnsureCreated();
}

After that, I added the Posts table in SSMS and scaffolded the database. In a newly generated context all Identity related DbSets and model configuring should be removed:
public partial class CloneIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
// ...

// Also, there is no need to add DbSet for Users, you will get warning that it hides the inherited one. 
public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail, "EmailIndex");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName, "UserNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);
            entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
        });

// Configuration for any additional entities, Posts in my case
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")
    ));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();

This time I decided to leave Id type as default for the sake of time:
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}

Thanks for the help. I think I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Safely assuming the Id property of User is the primary key, you're instantiating new Users without one:
User user = new User
{
  Email = model.Email,
  UserName = model.Email
};

since no value is auto-generated for the key and you're not setting one in your code either:
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
  entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
  ...
});

Removing the above configuration should solve the problem.
Update: also, please rename your custom class to e.g. ApplicationUser or AppUser.

Unfortunately no, that is not the case. After I remove it the following exception is thrown:
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Clone.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

@user729 which is funny because asp.net Identity takes care of assigning value to the Id column automatically.

@user729 Anyways, please remove ValueGeneratedNever and then proceed as commented above.
